# procedure which can pull out all the details of custom packages as per the username in the database

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to prepare a procedure which can pull out all the custom packages/triggers/functions/procedures and the source code of all custom packages/triggers/functions/procedures as per the username in the database.

Comment: so what did you try or what is the question?

Comment: Check out the view `all_source`: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-FD480C9E-F8DB-40DF-A04D-65765C45EA2F.htm

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
select DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl (object_type, object_name, owner) 
from dba_objects
where owner=  <user>
and object_type in ('PACKAGE','PACKAGE BODY','TRIGGER','FUNCTION','PROCEDURE');
```

This will return a clob data type. Write it to a file and that will give you the source code.